# Writing Data to Azure Blob Storage from Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, mount

I was able to mount Azure Blob Container to my Databricks DBFS and was able to read the data as well. While writing, I was able to see the files in the mount point from within databricks, however, it does not reflect in the blob storage. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saving the data frame?

```
df.write
.option("header", "true")
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.save("/mnt/result/someData.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your path is incorrect.
Check the mounted path with `dbutils.fs.mounts()` and ensure it is in your saving path. Also check that your saving path starts with `dbfs:/` and not `/dbfs/`.
Don’t hesitate to share your script.